# Combinatorics in Substitutes

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to substitute one reoccurring string in a list of cells with several options of strings to receive a list of all possible combinations.

For better understanding I prepared a sheet for you:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SKvwWIE9LqM9pYZ90r68h3Sl_Bl8Keid21Y0ukokqUM/edit?usp=sharing

In this example I have a list of expressions (A2:A) that all include the word "next" which I would like to have replaced with all the available options (B2:B) to create a list of all possible combinations (C2:C)

I know that in order to create all possible combinations of A2:A and B2:B I can use: 
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(rept(concatenate(A2:A&char(9)),counta(B2:B)),char(9)))
&" "&transpose(split(concatenate(rept(B2:B&char(9),counta(A2:A))),char(9))))

Comment: Dennis, it is best to put your data example in the message body so the question does not rely on third party services to retain its validity. I have done this for you with my edit. Hopefully my answer below also helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a find and replace. This does what you want:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
        REPLACE( TRANSPOSE( SPLIT( REPT( CONCATENATE(A2:A & CHAR(9)), COUNTA(B2:B) ), 
                                   CHAR(9)
                                 )
                          ), 
                 FIND( "next", TRANSPOSE( SPLIT( REPT( CONCATENATE(A2:A & CHAR(9)),
                                                       COUNTA(B2:B)
                                                     ),
                                                 CHAR(9)
                                               )
                                        )
                     ),
                 4,
                 TRANSPOSE( SPLIT( CONCATENATE( REPT( B2:B & CHAR(9), COUNTA(A2:A) ),
                                                CHAR(9)
                                              ),
                                   CHAR(9)
                                 )
                          )
               )
             )
```

## Explanation

The phrase `TRANSPOSE( SPLIT ( REPT( CONCATENATE(A2:A & CHAR(9)), COUNTA(B2:B) ), CHAR(9) ))` creates a column that repeats the items in Column A as many times as there are items in column B. The pattern repeats the entire list over and over. I'll call this `PHRASE1`.

The phrase `TRANSPOSE( SPLIT( CONCATENATE( REPT( B2:B & CHAR(9), COUNTA(A2:A)), CHAR(9) ), CHAR(9) ))` creates a column that repeats the items in Column B as many times as there are items in column A. The pattern repeats each item over and over. I'll call this `PHRASE2`.

Now you have two arrays of equal size. The goal is to find the word *next* in the first array and replace it with the word in the second array. To find the word *next*, I used `FIND("next", PHRASE1)`. That gives me the starting point for the replace phase. Let's call that `START`.

Finally, the replacement is simple: `REPLACE(PHRASE1, START, 4, PHRASE2)`. That's what you see in the code above.

I have tested this and it works.